# Reviewing counts all your comments as "actions"

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review

While reviewing first posts, I just came across a post which I have previously commented (*not* during the review process, that is). Surprisingly enough, the "I'm done" button was already active for me at the review page even though I haven't done anything yet:

[image]

I'm guessing every action done with the post *before* reviewing it will count for this, which leads me to two points:

1. If it's the way it should work, that means the system thinks I've already taken some kind of action about this particular post, hence it should not be in my review queue at all.
2. If it's a bug, the button should obviously be grayed out until I do something *on the review page*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now: if you have already taken some sort of action on a post, it won't be given to you in the First Posts queue. However, if you directly navigate to it (via reloading the page, back/forward, or permalink), it should still be reviewable, with the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button enabled and clickable by default.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was that when you were shown questions you had already acted upon the "I'm Done" button was grayed out.  That bug was fixed.

As to the question of whether it should skip posts you have already acted on entirely, that is one possibility (if you want to suggest that) but it was intentionally not done up until this point.  I imagine part of it is to give the reviewer an option of getting review credit for the action, and also that you might take more exhaustive actions when re-visiting the post in the review queue than when you first saw it.