# Comment voted up during review but not in the review queue does not mark the post as seen

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I saw [this answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/604) in the [first posts review queue](https://patents.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/469). I navigated to the question to edit it<sup>†</sup>. While I was on the question page, I upvoted a comment on the answer.

If I understand [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147493/reviewing-counts-all-your-comments-as-actions/147764#147764) correctly, my upvote of the comment should have counted as a review action. Yet the “I'm done” button didn't become enabled, even after a reload of https://patents.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/469/. Furthermore, when I return to the [review queue](https://patents.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts), I am still shown that post.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>It was a ninja edit after my edit from the review queue a couple of minutes before.</sub>

Comment: Reproduced [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/first-posts/743158) ([post link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415694/inline-function-versus-macro/12416024#12416024)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. If you have voted up a comment, we won't serve the post to you out of the review queue.

If you click through to the post from review and vote up a comment, you can refresh the review page to enable the "I'm Done" button.