# Previously voted for comments and does not trigger "I'm done"

Tags: bug, review, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment voted up during review but not in the review queue does not mark the post as seen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149143/comment-voted-up-during-review-but-not-in-the-review-queue-does-not-mark-the-pos)

I was reviewing first posts in the beta review. I came to a question that I had previously upvoted a comment on. Normally, upvoting a comment counts as an action and triggers the <kbd>I'm done</kbd> button. However, even though I had previously done this, the button would not trigger.

Comment: related/duplicate: [Action taken during review but not in the review queue does not mark the post as seen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149143/165773)

Comment: Related, except in my case, I had not yet opened up the review queue when I upvoted the comment. I wonder if that makes a difference?

Comment: well in a perfect world I would expect the system to either skip item or take into account my prior actions when opening it in review queue. Eg for close votes queue this seem to be the case: system is smart enough to skip questions I voted on before